# IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> in DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, listbox, ienumerable

How do you show this in DisplayMemberPath
so let's say I have the property

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Defaults{ get { return defaults; } }
```

in the class QuestionsFile and I want to put this in the following ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="QuestionsFile.Defaults" DisplayMemberPath="?"/>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? The key and the value? Why aren't you just using a POCO with two properties which are named appropriately for the object your KeyValuePair represents?

Comment: It's just the value which I want to show.. but I'll will do It like that

Answer (score 1):

You should set the DisplayMemberPath to Key or Value :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lst" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

and assign ItemSource in code behind :

```
lst.ItemsSource = Defaults;
```

or in xaml :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Defaults, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" x:Name="lst" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

Sources :

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/6561c53e-d671-44e4-9a4a-8ec6711cdc48
- [WPF: Setting ItemSource in XAML vs. code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147559/wpf-setting-itemsource-in-xaml-vs-code-behind)

Comment: You're proposing using a string for an ItemsSource: did you mean to put a binding here, mathieu?

Comment: But isn't this the same as what I did? I just did it in xaml?

Comment: found it: I did it like mathieu said, but I set the Defaults asEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="QuestionsFile.Defaults" DisplayMemberPath="?"/>
```

Do you mean this?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Defaults,ElementName=thisCtl}" DisplayMemberPath="?"/>
```

(Assuming thisCtl is the `x:Name` property value for the QuestionFile control)

Comment: the '?' was just for filling in what has to be there ;)